# addEventListener to a class for hide and show toggle

Tags: javascript

```js
        var my_toggle = document.getElementsByClassName('my_toggle');
        var my_toggle_button = document.getElementsByClassName('my_toggle_button');
        var my_toggle_array = [];
        var i;
        for(i = 0; i < my_toggle.length; i++){
            //my_toggle_array.push(0);
            my_toggle[i].style.display = "none";
            my_toggle_button[i].addEventListener("click", function(){
                if(my_toggle[i].style.display == "none" /* || my_toggle_array[i] == 0 */){
                  my_toggle[i].style.display = "block"; 
                  my_toggle_button[i].innerHTML = "- show less";
                  //my_toggle_array[i] = 1;
                } else {
                    my_toggle[i].style.display = "none"; 
                    my_toggle_button[i].innerHTML = "+ show more";
                    //my_toggle_array[i] = 0;
                }
            });
        }
```

```html
<div class="my_toggle">
  <p class="lead"></p>
</div>
<button class="my_toggle_button"></button>
<!-- and so on 11 times <div class="my_toggle><p class="lead"></p></div><button class="my_toggle_button"></button> -->
```

This code doesn't work when I upload it in cPanel or at least not all of it, it works until these lines

```js
for(i = 0; i < my_toggle.length; i++){
    //my_toggle_array.push(0);
    my_toggle[i].style.display = "none";
```

So basically the eventListener doesn't work, I tried like 2 hours in a script tag inside the page I wanted to do this toggle in but didn't work, then I put this code inside an external js file and I get like an error message "do not use functions inside a loop", why not using functions inside a loop?I commented out this code and used like this code which works but is way too long...

```js
var my_toggle = document.getElementsByClassName('my_toggle');
var my_toggle_button = document.getElementsByClassName('my_toggle_button');
var my_toggle_id = [];
var my_toggle_button_id = [];
var i;
for(i = 0; i < my_toggle.length; i++){
    my_toggle[i].setAttribute("id", "my_toggle_" + i.toString());
    my_toggle_id.push("my_toggle_" + i.toString());
    my_toggle_button[i].setAttribute("id", "my_toggle_button_" + i.toString());
    my_toggle_button_id.push("my_toggle_button_" + i.toString());
}

function function1(){
  let x = document.getElementById(my_toggle_id[0]); 
  let y = document.getElementById(my_toggle_button_id[0]);
  if (x.style.display === "none") {
    x.style.display = "block"; 
    y.innerHTML = "- mostra di meno";
  } else {
    x.style.display = "none"; y.innerHTML = "+ scopri di più";
  }
}

/* [...] and so on until */

function function11(){
    let x = document.getElementById(my_toggle_id[10]); 
    let y = document.getElementById(my_toggle_button_id[10]);
  if (x.style.display === "none") {
    x.style.display = "block"; 
    y.innerHTML = "- mostra di meno";
  } else {
    x.style.display = "none"; y.innerHTML = "+ scopri di più";
  }  
}
```

How can I add the EventListener to all classes without writing 130 lines of code?Is javascript the problem?Should I use PHP perhaps?Why?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem here is use of `var`.

> The var statement declares a function-scoped or globally-scoped variable

Read about [var](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/var) and [let](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/let)

When you declare `var i` ,  increment it inside the loop to make it `1` and then click function is called, the value of i remains `1` and hence `my_toggle[i]` becomes undefined and `my_toggle[i].style` would throw an error "Cannot read property 'style' of undefined". Use `let` for your index `i` to keep it block scoped. See below code:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<head>
    <title>The Alphabet</title>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
    <div class="my_toggle">
      <p class="lead">And so on 11 times</p>
    </div>
    <button class="my_toggle_button"></button>
</body>
<script type="text/javascript">
        var my_toggle = document.getElementsByClassName('my_toggle');
        var my_toggle_button = document.getElementsByClassName('my_toggle_button');
        var my_toggle_array = [];
     
        for(let i = 0; i < my_toggle.length; i++){
            //my_toggle_array.push(0);
            my_toggle[i].style.display = "none";
            my_toggle_button[i].addEventListener("click", function(){
                if(my_toggle[i].style.display == "none" /* || my_toggle_array[i] == 0 */){
                  my_toggle[i].style.display = "block"; 
                  my_toggle_button[i].innerHTML = "- show less";
                  //my_toggle_array[i] = 1;
                } else {
                    my_toggle[i].style.display = "none"; 
                    my_toggle_button[i].innerHTML = "+ show more";
                    //my_toggle_array[i] = 0;
                }
            });
        }


</script>

</html>
```

Comment: It works thank you Ravi! This scope issue doesn't make still any logical sense to me, I read the documentation but I still don't get it, anyway I didn't create javascript so I guess I will keep it in mind for future functions within loops or loops, I still get an alert in cPanel code editor "Don't make functions within a loop." but the code does what is supposed to do in the website so yeah have a nice day!